# Can't make lusca CSRF work with https: 403 forbidden

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, csrf

This is driving me nuts. I have tried reading the [lusca source code](https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca) but found it hard to understand.

Checked several examples too, but since each config is different, and the only debugging output I have are two strings to compare, I'd better ask for some help!

Here's the code server side:

```
app.use([
cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET),
session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({ url: MONGO_URL, autoReconnect: true }),
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  },
}), lusca({
  csrf: true,
  xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  xssProtection: true,
})]);
```

And from the clientside, I send Ajax `POST` requests with the `x-csrf-token:l0gH3xmssge53E/p2NsJ4dGnHaSLdPeZ+bEWs=` header in it:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN
  }
});
```

Crazy thing is, it's working locally, but as soon as I go `https` in `production`, I get the `403 Forbidden` error message.

Here are the versions I use:

```
"cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
"express-session": "1.15.3",
"lusca": "1.5.1",
```

Also I read this from the [express/session doc](https://github.com/expressjs/session):

> Note Since version 1.5.0, the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work.

But as far as I'm concerned, I need to store some persistent ID of the users (longer than the session). I need to use cookies for that, right?

I'd like to understand better on the whole session/cookie thing, but until now I never found any useful resource on the topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your Node.js server behind a proxy you will need to set `trust proxy` to true:

```
var isProductionEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

app.use([
cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET),
session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({ url: MONGO_URL, autoReconnect: true }),
  proxy: isProductionEnv,
  cookie: {
    secure:isPrudictionEnv,
  },
}), lusca({
  csrf: true,
  xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  xssProtection: true,
})]);


app.set('trust proxy', isProductionEnv);
```

Check out this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802322/node-js-express-session-what-does-the-proxy-option-do). Also check out this page on [Express behind proxies](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

Comment: My app is hosted in docker and a nginx does some routing first, is that what should be called a proxy? Anyway, I tried the `trust proxy` thing and it doesn't work. :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like you might need to add a `proxy` setting to the session middleware options as well. I will edit the answer so you can take a look.

Comment: Still no luck. But I'm not sure this is it: Nginx doesn't do HTTP proxying and docker shouldn't be an issue here. My feeling is that this has to do with the cookie being secure+used in a session ...