# Avoid sign-in popup when running hmtl page with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, express-session

We're creating a web app in node.js. For this we're following [this example](https://github.com/moribvndvs/passport-examples/tree/master/example-simple) to see how things are done. Whenever we work with an `express-session` there is a credential pop-up displayed when accessing the page in the browser.

[image: pop-up displayed]

```js
  app.use(session({
    proxy: true,
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    rolling: true,
    name: 'sid', 
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 20 * 60 * 1000
    }
  }));
```

Searching the web I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802322/node-js-express-session-what-does-the-proxy-option-do) which talks about setting the `proxy` setting in the `session`. However, after trying all options we still get the pop-up. Installing stuff through npm works fine without issue, even loading pages where no `express-session` are used.

How can we avoid this pop-up? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally nailed this down. It was something completely unrelated. As we are using `bootstrap 4` we get the `sign in` pop up when we don't include the correct javascript files required by `bootstrap` at the end of the HTML page:

```html
<body>
    <!-- Other html code -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Including this at the end of the page removed the annoying pop-up.