# req.session in express-session not persisting

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var http = require('http')
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'sdlfjljrowuroweu',
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.get('/test', test);
function test(req, res) {
    var sess = req.session;
    console.log('before', sess);
    if (sess.views) {
        sess.views++
        req.session.save();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
        res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
        res.end();
    } else {
        sess.views = 1;
        req.session.save();
        res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
    }
    console.log('after', sess);
    return;
}

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8181);
```

And reloading the page, I just keep getting the view count 0 message.

Checking the console, this is the output every time:

```
before { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true } }
after { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  views: 1 }
```

So it doesn't seem to be saving at all

Comment: Are you using a secure connection? aka `https://`, I suspect you aren't, but you've set the `secure` flag to true inside your `express.session(...)`, which means you'll never be able to access the cookie (so sessions won't work correctly).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change  `cookie: { secure: true }`to   `cookie: { secure: false }`

using **secure** flag means that the cookie will be set on Https only.

Comment: Thanks for copying my comment into an answer.

Comment: I didnt see your comment

Comment: Yep, that was the reason. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Thank you!! same problem for days

Comment: This is indeed the problem, however one could implement `cookie: { secure: app.get('env') === 'production' }` so that the SSL is required only when the app goes live.

Comment: This just saved my a**  -----------------------

  `    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV ? true : false,`